# Converting polyline data to polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, convert, line, geometry-conversion

I am trying to convert some polyline coastline data into a polygon that I can use to clip/subset back other data sets by this polygon.  There are some small gaps in the coastline data, which FeatureToPolygon struggles to get just how I want it.  Any advice?

Comment: Could you clarify the word small gaps, i mean how much in units? If small then have you tried EXTEND tool in arc map?.

Answer (score 1):

try the tool [Split Polygons With Lines](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cd6b2d45df654245b7806a896670a431). At first you have to create a polygon which covers the whole area. Then use the tool. After using the tool you can easily delete the parts which doesn't matter to you.